# wxErlang openGL text example

Tags: opengl, wxerlang

Does anyone have a working example on how to get a text drawn in openGL, the erlang bindings?

Im using a texture right now to load the one created by wxBitmap.  And I am considering moving the GL code to Java or C++.

Comment: https://github.com/asceth/nehe_erlang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run "wx:demo()" from the erlang shell, it contains one example of how to do it.
Click OpenGL and have a look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal Elixir example looks like this:
Create the module (top).
Execute in terminal (middle).
Choose 'gl' in Window with wxExamples (bottom):

[image]